# What does (pandas.core.series.Series) mean in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm working on a Dataframe exercise in Python and below is the type of one column:

pandas.core.series.Series

I've already reviewed resources on Dataframe structures, but couldn't find explanation of this type or how "series" is different than "Series".

Can anyone please explain to me what does "core", "series" and "Series" mean? and why the type has these three components?

Thanks

Comment: For these types of questions it's usually better to refer to the documentiation which for this case can be found here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html

In this case, you are using module named pandas, which has grouped its core functionalities under module core, and it has a method series under core.

Comment: Thanks for your info & tip. I spent some time on documentation but couldn't find an explanation of this grouping.

Answer (score -1):

you will find information about pandas here :

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html

pandas is a module (library) that you can use in python. 
`core.series.Series` are "sub-module" object or function from your pandas library

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've seen this documentation before but I can't find an explanation of how "series" is different than "Series".

Comment: Series is a "sub-module"  of series. "pandas" contain "core" that contain "series" that contain "Series"

Comment: @Dadep VERY CLEAR! thanks